# How to save poses in pose library permanently in blend file? (Blender 4.0)

Tags: pose-mode, blend-files, library

So I want to transfer my blend file to another computer and I already have my saved poses in my pose library, and I even auto pack resources before saving it. However, when I open the file to my other computer, the poses are all gone. Is there a way to save the poses permanently?